How to Properly Distribute Files in Blazor’s RenderMode.Auto?
I’m working with a Blazor project and using RenderMode.Auto for my components. I understand that this mode initially renders components on the server side and then switches to client-side rendering once the WebAssembly files are downloaded. However, I’m unclear about the seperation of main and Client pages/components,
Even in the template project of visual studio (RenderModeAuto with Interactivity set at Per Page/Component), Client project has the Counter.razor page while Weather.razor is in the main project. I can't understand why there's a seperation of components between the two projects while we can simply change render mode for each page/component

I'm assuming the template you selected was RenderModeAuto with Interactivity set at Per Page/Component.
The Server project references the Client project, so it can see all the razor components in the Client project.  Note in the Server Program:
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(SO78467379.Client._Imports).Assembly);

The converse is not true.  The WASM project can only see components in itself and libraries it references.
So any pages/components that should be WASM rendered need to be in the Client project or a library it can reference.

here is what i get from your answer: put WASM and Auto rendered pages on .Client project and put ONLY server-side rendered pages in main project. Is that right?

Yes that summarises it.
